# Creating an arrow

Tags: tables, lists, tikz-arrows

I am in trouble with one output that I want to show on Latex. Is possible to do the following pictures, with some overleaf code?
[image]

Comment: You don't need a sledge hammer like tikz to do that. A simple `\xrightarrow` from `amsmath` will do it.

Comment: Which part of the image is the problematic part? The arrow with text above it? The alignment? Something else? Please clarify.

Comment: I am able only to build the first part, so the first 3 intervals [0,0.3] till [0.6,1]. I do not know how insert the arrow with "some text here" and another list with 3 intervals on the right side

Comment: Please show how you achieved the first part of the image by adding a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) to your question. Regarding the arrow with text: Bernard already mentioned `\xrightarrow` which should work perfectly fine here. Side note: You might also want to change the title of your question to something more meaningful as this whole site is about  questions concerning LaTeX.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about this? I'm not sure whether you want to align your intervals somehow. The following solution requires the `amsmath`-package.

```
\begin{tabular}{ll}
   1. & [0, 0.30]  \\
   2. & [0.3, 0.6] \\
   3. & [0.6, 1]
\end{tabular}
$\xrightarrow{\text{Some text here}}$
\begin{tabular}{ll}
   1. & [0,7]  \\
   2. & [7,12] \\
   3. & [12,30]
\end{tabular}
```

[image]

---

EDIT: After a discussion about the alignment in the comments, try the following:

```
\begin{tabular}{ll@{\ }r} % <----- here you can play around with your tabular.
                          % The '@{\ }' says we want to have a normal space between the first and the second element. You could try @{\,} or @{} instead
                          % The last 'r' specifies the alignment of the last column. Maybe you want to have 'l' here.
   1. & [0,   & 0.30] \\
   2. & [0.3, & 0.6]  \\
   3. & [0.6, & 1]
\end{tabular}
% Same for the second tabular.
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: Is also possible to align the intervals?

Comment: @John_maddon: Aligning intervals is also possible. How exactly does the expected alignment look like? Does the following image contain the expected output? https://i.stack.imgur.com/FM20w.png

Comment: @leandriis The first one is perfect :)

Comment: @John_maddon I added a version with aligned intervals.

Answer (score 3):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\[
\begin{array}{ll@{}r}
1. & [0,&0.30]\\
2. & [0.3,&0.6]\\
3. & [0.6,&1]
\end{array}
\xrightarrow{\text{some text here}}
\begin{array}{ll@{}r}
1. & [0,&7]\\
2. & [7,&12]\\
3. & [12,&30]
\end{array}\\
\]
\end{document}
```